# can you help me with this error jrs-rst php client v2

Tags: php, jasper-reports

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Jaspersoft\Exception\RESTRequestException' with message 'An unexpected HTTP status code was returned by the server' in C:\wamp\www\new_hris\vendor\jaspersoft\rest-client\src\Jaspersoft\Tool\RESTRequest.php:364 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\wamp\www\new_hris\vendor\jaspersoft\rest-client\src\Jaspersoft\Tool\RESTRequest.php(451): Jaspersoft\Tool\RESTRequest->handleError(404, Array, '<html><head><ti...') 
#1 C:\wamp\www\new_hris\vendor\jaspersoft\rest-client\src\Jaspersoft\Client\Client.php(158): Jaspersoft\Tool\RESTRequest->prepAndSend('http://localhos...', Array, 'GET', NULL, true, 'application/jso...', 'application/jso...') 
#2 C:\wamp\www\new_hris\report.php(14): Jaspersoft\Client\Client->serverInfo() #3 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\new_hris\vendor\jaspersoft\rest-client\src\Jaspersoft\Tool\RESTRequest.php on line 364"
```

I got this error and I dont know how to debug it.

by the way this is my code below:

```
    require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

    use Jaspersoft\Client\Client;
    $c = new Client(
            "http://localhost:3307/jasperserver",
            "jasperadmin",
            "password"

           );       

  $js = $c->jobService();               
  $c->setRequestTimeout(60); 
  $info = $c->serverInfo();

   $report = $c->reportService()->runReport('/reports/samples/AllAccounts', 'html');
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommended you that call the report by uri. Example:
http://ip:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&standAlone=true&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=%2Freports%2Fviaticos&reportUnit=%2Freports%2Fviaticos%2FrptOrdenMovilizacionByCar&j_username=jasperreportadmin&j_password=jasperreportadmin&P_FECHA1=02/08/2016&P_FECHA2=25/08/2016&P_VEH_CODIGO=52&output=pdf